# When is the latest time to apply for UK standard visitor visa?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas

If I am traveling to the United Kingdom on 1 February 2022, When is the latest time to apply for the visa taking into account the Christmas holiday?

P.S. I want to apply as late as possible to arrange my bank statement and at the same time I don’t want it to be very late so I cannot catch on if there is any problem or delay from the Embassy.

Comment: There is not "lastest time". Just that if you deleay too much, the probability to get the visa in time diminishes. In any case, to answer your question (with typical times), you should check your local embassy, or you should write here from which country you are applying and your nationality (it depends on both).

Comment: I am an Iraqi and I am applying from Iraq

Answer (score 2):

The ‘standard’ processing time is 3 weeks, so in theory you could wait until as late as 10 January 2022 to apply, providing you can get an immediate appointment at the visa application centre.

You might be able to use the priority service (decision within 5 days) if it’s available at the centre where you’ll be applying.

However, a decision within these timescales is *not* guaranteed, even if you pay for priority. So in practice, the answer is to apply within the 3 month period prior to your intended travel date as soon as you have all the required supporting documents.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/visa-decision-waiting-times-applications-outside-the-uk